# Using FindPagesWithCriteria in Episerver returns no results

Tags: episerver

i wonder if someone else has come accross this issue. I am trying to use FindPagesWithCriteria and i am creating my property criteria as like this:

```
PropertyCriteria dateCriteria = new PropertyCriteria();
dateCriteria.Condition = CompareCondition.GreaterThan;
dateCriteria.Name = "PageStopPublish";                
dateCriteria.Type = PropertyDataType.Date;
dateCriteria.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
dateCriteria.Required = true;
```

so i am trying to find all the pages that are not expired. However, some pages may not have StopPublish property set in which case Datetime.MaxValue should be used. But in this particular case (no StopPublish value set) FindPagesWithCriteria will not return any results. Is there a reason for this or is it a bug? As a workaround, i am returning using PageTypeName criteria and then applying some additional filterin for returned PageDataCollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FindPagesWithCriteria will only give you published pages (and pages that the current user have access to) so having StopPublish as a criteria is not necessary.

FindAllPagesWithCriteria will return all pages, including unpublished pages and pages the current user does not have access to.

Comment: Agree, or do a FilterByVisitor since that will also only include non-expired pages (depending on what you need to achieve).

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. I think i understand the concept behind these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

EPiServer properties with an empty value are never stored in the database. If you access it from code, it will always be null.

To search for a null property using PropertyCriteria, set the [IsNull](http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms6.1/html/P_EPiServer_PropertyCriteria_IsNull.htm) property to true

Comment: Hi, i understand that empty properties in episerver return null, but not in every case. If not specified the StopPublish property returns Datetime.MaxValue if you call GetPage. I assumed that FindPagesWithCriteria would do the same. By the way, setting IsNull didn't do the trick either.